# Can you recommend Game Engine that can run on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

I am getting a raspberry pi 3, I am basically a 3D Artist and I create games using Unity 3d for now. But I am getting pi 3 to see what is the lowest I can go to have a minimal artist machine. I don't care even if it really bad but would be great to know if anyone has ever tried.

Thank you,
Waqas

Answer (score 1):

I did a research and I found 2 games engines that could possibly run:

1. Construct 2, it can run in a browser over pi.
2. Raylib which is available on Github

Have a look if anyone is interested!

Waqas

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at those:

1. [AppGameKit](https://www.appgamekit.com/agk-pi/)
2. [Urho3D](https://urho3d.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Godot engine is a game engine which can run on the raspberry pi 3.
To install it on Raspberry pi 3 , download [Pi-apps](https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps)

and go to Games -> Godot Engine -> install .
For tutorials , go to [Godot's Design Philosophy](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction/godot_design_philosophy.html)

For more information , go to [https://godotengine.org](https://godotengine.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyGame as the Raspberry Pi supports Python. I have been using Java, with Java 2D API, because JavaFX was removed for the Pi.